# Automatically takes a '/'(slash) in textInput field using react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

If i entered text in text-input field then automatically it takes a '/'(slash) in between Month and Year.

Here is my code:

```
  handleMMYYYY = (text) => {
     this.setState({ MMYYYY: text })
  }
 <TextInput
       underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
       autoCapitalize="none"
       placeholder="MM/YYYY"
       style={{textAlign:'center'}}
       placeholderTextColor="grey"
       returnKeyType='next'
       onChangeText={this.handleMMYYYY}
       onSubmitEditing={(event)=>{
       this.refs.third.focus();
       }}
      />
```

Here is my screenshot:[image]

Comment: Please update your question with the whole component implementation. hen I would be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be this

```
 handleMMYYYY = (text) => {
      formated = text;
      if(formated.length==2){
        //formated = text +'/';
        if(this.state.getCardDate.indexOf('/') == -1){
          formated = text +'/';
        }

      }
    this.setState({ getCardDate: formated })    
}
```

not flexible but the most simple i can think.

Comment: @Lavaraju hi i just tried your solution and it is not working. Can you please help me out

Comment: Did u change your state value

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of react components already out there to do this. It's called masked input.

Try this one;
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask